# Adding company logo to newsfeed sharing links

Tags: facebook-apps, feed

I have a native *iOS* & *Blackberry* App. You can create personalized videos.

When people share their video clip on *Facebook*, I would like the company logo and the accompanying link to go through to our website (not FB App page).

*Instagram*, *Blackberry* and *Twitter* all do this.

For e.g. when someone uploads an *Instagram* photo - it has the *Instagram* logo, with link to their website underneath the upload.

Do you know how I can do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First your Facebook app will need to request manage_feed permissions from the user.  Once you have manage_feed, you can http POST the posting using the Graph API to put the stream item into their feed. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ for further info.